# Unsupported [References to variables aren't supported yet] in android jetpack compose

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to use reference operator like  `onClick = ::onClose` in below code

```
@Composable
    fun HeaderIcons(onClose: () -> Unit) {
    
        ConstraintLayout(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .wrapContentHeight()
        ) {
                IconButton(
                    onClick = (::onClose)()
                ) {
                    Image(imageVector = ImageVector.vectorResource(id = R.drawable.ic_close), contentDescription = null)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am facing error: **Unsupported [References to variables aren't supported yet]**

Anyone have idea how to solve it or any other alternative?

ThankYou in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composable function reference is not yet supported. You need to use:

```
onClick = {onClose()}
```

Answer (score 3):

`onClick = (::onClose)()` isn't a valid syntax. You can't call a function reference.

Use `onClick = onClose` or `onClick = { onClose() }`.

Comment: I think it's not about syntax problem I am currently using 'onClick = { onClose() }' this syntax.
I want try with reference like 'onClick = (::onClose)()' or 'onClick = ::onClose' but I thought as per @Gabriele answer "Composable function reference is not yet supported". 

Thank You Arpit